# Почему не устанавливается библиотека xhtml2pdf?

Tags: python, django

Господа, подскажите в чем может быть проблема - не устанавливается библиотека xhtml2pdf, для преобразования *HTML* to *PDF*, при команде:

```
pip install xhtml2pdf
```

выдается ошибка и вот в конце такое:

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe4' in file C:\Users\775D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppjtu0867.py on line 3, but no encoding declared; see python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263 for details error: command 'c:\\users\\днс\\desktop\\travels\\trv_env\\scripts\\python.exe' failed with exit status 1

Command "c:\users\днс\desktop\travels\trv_env\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\775D~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6qhqh33p\\xhtml2pdf\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record C:\Users\775D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rwupnme8\install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\днс\desktop\travels\trv_env\include\site\python3.6\xhtml2pdf" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\775D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6qhqh33p\xhtml2pdf\
```

ОС Windows 10, Django 2.0, Python 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, вся проблема в том, что у вас имя пользователя кириллицей.

> c:\users\днс\desktop\

Comment: Но абсолютно все другие (десятки) библиотек устанавливаются нормально! Только эта одна ругается ( Такое может быть? И если реально в этом проблема - как можно обойти это препятствие? "днс" администратор, на нем строится весь проект, имя его не поменять никак ((

Comment: Да такое вполне может быть. А собственно говоря, в чём проблема перейти в настройки и переименовать текущий аккаунт (имя пользователя) ?

Comment: Я изменил имя в настройках, перегрузился, теперь имя визуально  отображается новое на латинице, НО во всех путях по прежнему "днс" стоит. Захожу в папку проекта, опять C:\Users\днс\... Бесит Windows.

Comment: В гугл по запросу `windows 10 смена имени администратора путь не меняется` нашёл варианты решения вашей проблемы. Ссылку не пишу, т.к. наказуемо)

Comment: Попробовал поискать, нашел способы - к сожалению ни один не сработал, это реально непростая задача в этом поганом Windows изменить пути. Попробовал создать нового пользователя с латинским именем, на нем протестил установку (в новой вирт среде) - получилось, установка прошла без проблем, так что дело реально было в русскоязычном имене пользователя. Придется проект переносить в новую вирт среду нового пользователя. Спасибо! Отметил решением.